# How can I in smarty get a array's special name's value?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a PHP array like below:

```
$list = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'switch',
        'value'=>'cisco'
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'switchport',
        'value'=>'2'
    )
);
```

How can I get `name='switch'` or `name='switchport'`'s item in one step?

because this is in `smarty` template, there is the img

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/api.php?switch={$my_need_switch_value}&switchport={$my_need_switchport_value}">
```

So, how can I get the `my_need_switch_value` from `$list` in one step?

Comment: You _could_ structure your array differently before passing it to Smarty, it makes more sense to pass the exact values you need in to your templates and have all your logic for controlling those values outside of the template...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{assign}` to assign new variables.

```
{foreach from=$list item=customfield}
    {if $customfield.name=='switch'}
        {assign var=switch value=$customfield.value}
    {elseif $customfield.name=='switchport'}
        {assign var=portname value=$customfield.value}
    {/if}

{/foreach}
```

then you can use the `$switch` and `$switchport` directily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `{$list.0}` or `{$list.0.name}`? If I understood what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$list[0].name
$list[1].name
```

I do not believe there is a one shoot. You should at least iterate the array and compare the value with what you need.

Comment: this can not determine the name whether is `switch ` or `switchport`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, you can create a function with the array and the name you want to find as parameters, then loop through it and get its value. Like so:

```
$list = [
    [
        'name'=>'switch',
        'value'=>'cisco'
    ],
    [
        'name'=>'switchport',
        'value'=>'2'
    ]
];

function getValue($array, $name) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value['name'] == $name) {
            echo $value['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

If you call it using 'switch' as name parameter it will echo 'cisco', and if you change it to 'switchport', it will echo '2'. Then you can use it on your structure like so:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/api.php?switch={getValue($list,'switch')}&switchport={getValue($list,'switchport')}">
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, this is my requirement, but how can I get it in the smary template? define the function in smarty.

Comment: @244boy I've never worked with smarty. But can't you just [open a php block](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl) like so, and put the function inside it?